# How to add linebreaks to a stream reader if conditions are met

Tags: c#, stream

So I have code that needs to check if the file has already been split every 50 characters. 99% of the time it will come to me already split, where each line is 50 characters, however there is an off chance that it may come to me as a single line, and I need to add a linebreak every 50 characters. This file will always come to me as a stream.

Once I have the properly formatted file, I process it as needed.

However, I am uncertain how I can check if the stream is properly formatted.

Here is the code I have to check if the first line if larger than 50 characters(an indicator it may need to be split).

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(s);
var firstLineCount = streamReader.ReadLines().Count();
if(firstLineCount > 50)
{
//code to add line breaks
}

//once the file is good
using(var trackReader = new TrackingTextReader(streamReader))
{
//do biz logic
}
```

How can I add linebreaks to a stream reader?

Comment: You want to write to a **reader**. Sounds funny.

Comment: By streamReader.ReadLines().Count() you are getting number of lines in the file not number of characters in a line.

Answer (score 1):

I would add all lines to a `List<string>`. (Line by line)
Do the check for each item in the list (using `for`, not `foreach`, because we will be inserting items).

If some item in the list has more than 50 characters.
Add an item to the next index of the list using `item.SubString(50)` (all the string after the 50th character).
And cut the final of the item at current index using `YourList[i] = YourList[i].SubString(0,50)`.

---

Funny comment someone did helped for this:
You can also create a StreamWriter to write the Stream you're reading with the corrections.
Then you get the produced Stream and pass it forward to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write anything to `TextReader`, because... it is a reader. The option here is to make a well-formed copy of data:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetWellFormedData(Stream s)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
                if (nextLine.Length > 50)
                {
                    // break the line into 50-chars fragments and yield return fragments
                }
                else
                    yield return nextLine;
            }
        }
    }
```